# Make a Typescript object property a generic array of objects?

Tags: typescript

I'm quite new to using typescript and I'm wanting to make a simple object that holds data relating to a specific users message logs. Here is the basic structure I have at the minute:

```
export class UserMessageLog {
    date: string;
    askedBy: string;
    msgLogs: { id: string, detail: string }[];

}
```

When I try to push an object in the format of `{ id, detail}` to the `msgLogs` property, I get an error in the console stating the `msgLogs` is undefined. I'm assuming I need to initialize this property in a constructor perhaps? What's the best way to do that?

Comment: You can just instantiate it in one line `msgLogs: { id: string, detail: string }[] = [];`

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to instantiate an array before you can push anything to it. e.g.

```
const userMessageLog: UserMessageLog = {};
userMessageLog.msgLogs = [];
userMessageLog.msLogs.push(...);
```